# Wireless Very weak and slow on Ubuntu Macbook pro 8.3?

Tags: wireless, macbook-pro

The question says it all. I have ubuntu running on a macbook pro 8.3. It connects but the signal is very weak. When I boot using the Mac, the wireless is very fast and reliable. The relevant output nm-tool is

> Type:              802.11 WiFi   Driver:            b43   State:
>   connected   Default:           yes   HW Address:
>   28:CF:DA:D4:3B:C4
>
> Capabilities:
>
> Wireless Properties
>       WEP Encryption:  yes
>       WPA Encryption:  yes
>       WPA2 Encryption: yes
>
> Wireless Access Points 
>       wifi-nu:         Infra, 00:24:6C:81:14:00, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA2 Enterprise
>       Milk Digital Admin: Infra, 0C:85:25:68:BB:D3, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA WPA2
>       Legs Admin:      Infra, 0C:85:25:68:BB:D5, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA WPA2

It keeps droping and is significantly slower. Also, I installed the driver as recommended by the [ubuntu macbook support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric#Wireless)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The propriary drive is known to have issues on macs with power saving features. Try turing them off.

`sudo iwconfig eth1 power off`

The interface might be different.  Also try the open source driver a lot has changed in Ubuntu 12.

Comment: I already tried this. I even added it into a file in /etc/pm/power.d/wireless. In any case, where do I get the open source one from?

Comment: I also followed some instruction [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/688146) , but the signal is still significantly lower than the signal when in mac.

Comment: Just undo the instructions where you blacklisted the module. The open source driver will takeover. It may not work. But it's worth a try. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2) has wireless working out of the box in 12.04, though scrolling down the page it says it doesn't. Then there is [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/784655) And [This may be of help](http://wiki.debian.org/MacBook/Wireless) I have the same chip and the open source (default) driver works quite well.

Comment: Don't worry about signal too much. OS X and Linux "measure differently". Worry about speed, and connection. If you get full speed, and constant connection, then your fine. Strength of signal is not measured the same between operating systems.

Comment: `Just undo the instructions where you blacklisted the module.`  
I am sorry, which one?

Comment: and this is what lpsci gives: `Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n`

Comment: Try http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966236 post #3

Comment: I noticed that this is happening only at work where wifi requires login after you connect through the browser. Network sometimes even "times out". Could the network be the issue? Because at home wireless signal is good and does not drop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6542/discussion-between-coteyr-and-ali)